# log() negative number throwing domain error

Tags: julia

I am attempting to broadcast the log function in a script I am writing.

It is throwing a domain error

```
julia> log(100)
4.605170185988092

julia> log(-100)
ERROR: DomainError:
```

Is there a way around this at all? I have a mix of - , + in my array.

Comment: The logarithm function is only defined over `[0, Inf]`. Why do you need `log(-100)`? Can you live with `log(abs(-100))` instead?

Comment: Just an example I'm taking the log of a calculation output some are neg, some pos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For real input the log function returns real numbers. If the log function were to promote the type of `log(-100)` automatically (to complex numbers) it would be type unstable.

You can do `log(complex(-100))` to get complex output (or `log.(complex.(array))` for your array of numbers).